# Implementing a single module controller while leaving the controller out of the URL

Tags: url, magento, controller

I'd like to have one module controller implement the different action methods, but I don't want the URLs to come out like

```
www.example.com/module/index/action1  
www.example.com/module/index/action2  
www.example.com/module/index/action3
```

where `/index/` takes us to the "IndexController". To have the URLs like I want

```
www.example.com/module/action1  
www.example.com/module/action2  
www.example.com/module/action3
```

I would need to create a controller class for *every* action method. What is the best way to get the URLs I want with the different action methods in one nice class/file/controller? I was wondering if there was a way besides URL rewrites. If not, could you point me to a good URL rewriting tutorial for Magento?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do an URL rewrite at the web server, you can also do, essentially, an URL rewrite inside Magento's code. For example, you can override the function Match within Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard like so:

```
/* after getting the controller name and action name... */
if ((strcmp($module, 'myModuleName') == 0) && (strcmp($action, 'index') == 0)) {
    $action = $controller;
    $controller = 'index';
}
/* before checking if this place should be secure and instantiate controller class
```

I think URL rewrite at the web server will be cleaner and more manageable, though.

If you are using Magento's URL rewrite, you'll probably need to specify a rule for every action, such as:

```
Type: custom
Request Path: myModuleName/hello
Target Path: myModuleName/index/hello
```

You can specify these URL rewrite rules in the admin, under Catalog > URL Rewrite Management

Answer (score 0):

There is no real reason to violate Magento `reuter/controller/action` scheme. For any deviation they created the URL rewrites functional.

You can create Url rewrite even omitting the `module` part. Creating URL rewrites is really simple, I don't think you need tutorial for that, just open admin panel, go to *Catalog->Url Rewrites Management*. Click on create new rewrite, choose **Custom** type, add the desired uri part to *Request Path* (`module/action`), and the actual uri to the *Target Path* (`module/controller/action`).